# regression with constraints on weights python

Tags: regression, python, optimization

I want to do a regression. the y series is provided, so does a dataframe(df) with columns x1,x2,x3...,xn.
I would like to have the regression as follows:
y=b0+b1x1+b2x2+b3x3+...+bnxn
where bi(i=1,2,3...,n) is in (0,1) and the sum of b1+b2+b3+...bn<=1

I was told to use scipy.optimize.minimize, but reading through the guidance(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), I still had no clue how to write the code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the solutions [posted here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+constrain*+inequality+is%3Aanswer.)